# Why getGroupView is not calling in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

This is my code . 
l
when i am running it,nothing comes on emulator screen. even i am passing value for parent group.

i put break point also on getGroupView but this method not get calling.

// class for value in parent group

```
public class ArrayForList
{
    public static String[] grp ={"Car"};
}
```

// Activity

```
public class ExpandableActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListView ev;
    ExpandableAdapter adp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable);

        ev = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.el);
        ev.setAdapter(new ExpandableAdapter(this));
    }
    }
```

//Adapter

```
public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context myContext;
    public ExpandableAdapter(Context con)
    {
        this.myContext = con;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
        }

        TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_group);
        tvGroupName.setText(ArrayForList.grp[groupPosition]);

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    }
```

//xml group_row

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

//xml main

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/el"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ExpandableAdapter class change return value of some methods.like getGroupCount() return size 0,its change to group size. getGroup(int groupPosition),it also return null value, change
value of group at groupPosition.